# Django: Multiple inheritance from abstract classes with meta

Tags: python, django, multiple-inheritance, metaclass

I have a model that inherit from 2 abstract models with attributes in their meta-classes.

How can I make it inherit the metas from both parent classes? It seems like it only inherit the meta of the class written first.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Normal rules for Python's multiple inheritance apply when using it in Django. That means that if multiple parents have the `Meta` class, only the `Meta` of the first parent will be used. Others will be ignored.

See this URL for more info
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#multiple-inheritance